# Sort Pandas Dataframe by substrings of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

Given a DataFrame:

```
    name             email
0   Carl    carl@yahoo.com
1    Bob     bob@gmail.com
2  Alice   alice@yahoo.com
3  David  dave@hotmail.com
4    Eve     eve@gmail.com
```

How can it be sorted according to the email's domain name (alphabetically, ascending), and then, within each domain group, according to the string before the "@"?

The result of sorting the above should then be:

```
    name             email
0    Bob     bob@gmail.com
1    Eve     eve@gmail.com
2  David  dave@hotmail.com
3  Alice   alice@yahoo.com
4   Carl    carl@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`sorted` + `reindex`

```
df = df.set_index('email')
df.reindex(sorted(df.index, key=lambda x: x.split('@')[::-1])).reset_index()

              email   name
0     bob@gmail.com    Bob
1     eve@gmail.com    Eve
2  dave@hotmail.com  David
3   alice@yahoo.com  Alice
4    carl@yahoo.com   Carl
```

---

**Option 2**
`sorted` + `pd.DataFrame`
As an alternative, you can ditch the `reindex` call from Option 1 by re-creating a new DataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    sorted(df.values, key=lambda x: x[1].split('@')[::-1]), 
    columns=df.columns
)

    name             email
0    Bob     bob@gmail.com
1    Eve     eve@gmail.com
2  David  dave@hotmail.com
3  Alice   alice@yahoo.com
4   Carl    carl@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Is it possible to do Option 2 with the column name instead of x[1]? I tried x["email"] and I get an error.

Comment: @IamTheWalrus No, it isn't possible. `sorted` operates on df.values, and those can only be indexed with integers.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks. I managed to get the column index with  df.columns.get_loc("email") and use it with your solution. I prefer it since my actual dataframe reads many columns from a csv and I sometimes change which are included in the dataframe and in which order.

Comment: @IamTheWalrus very innovative! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
idx = df['email'].str.split('@', expand=True).sort_values([1,0]).index
df = df.reindex(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    name             email
0    Bob     bob@gmail.com
1    Eve     eve@gmail.com
2  David  dave@hotmail.com
3  Alice   alice@yahoo.com
4   Carl    carl@yahoo.com
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for unique default indices
2. Then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values to new `DataFrame` and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
3. Last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to new order

Comment: Brilliant! Just awesome! This is a great answer.