# Natural sorting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, natsort

I have this data in pandas

```
data = [
        ['ID', 'Time', 'oneMissing', 'singleValue', 'empty', 'oneEmpty'],
        ['CS1-1', 1,  10000, None, None, 0],
        ['CS1-2', 2, 20000, 0.0,  None, 0],
        ['CS1-1', 2, 30000, None, None, 0],
        ['CS1-2', 1,  10000, None, None, None],
        ['CS1-11', 1, None,  0.0,  None, None],
        ['CS1-2', 3, 30000, None, None, None]
    ]
```

that I try to sort by ID and Time columns so the result should be like

```
        'CS1-1', 1,  10000, None, None, 0
        'CS1-1', 2, 30000, None, None, 0
        'CS1-2', 1,  10000, None, None, None
        'CS1-2', 2, 20000, 0.0,  None, 0
        'CS1-2', 3, 30000, None, None, None
        'CS1-11', 1, None,  0.0,  None, None
    ]
```

I'm using pandas dataframe for the sorting, also tried together with natsort, but I can't get it to work. Either I get errors that the index includes duplicates (I use ID as the index) or it sorts by string values.

The ID here is just an example. I don't know what format it will be, it might be NUMBER-LETTER or NUMBER LETTER NUMBER. I just need to compare all numbers as a number. I've looked at "natsort" and that seems to do correct for an array. So I think it should be possible to use that to sort the ID and then re-index the data.

I've looked at multiple sources like these, but without any luck:
[Alphanumeric sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528850/how-to-sort-descending-an-alphanumeric-pandas-index) [Sort dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913881/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-column-that-has-both-numbers-and-strings?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.extract`, `sort_values`, then use the index to reindex `df`.

```
idx = (df.assign(ID2=df.ID.str.extract(r'(\d+)$').astype(int))
         .sort_values(['ID2', 'Time'])
         .index)

df.iloc[idx]

       ID  Time  oneMissing  singleValue empty  oneEmpty
0   CS1-1     1     10000.0          NaN  None       0.0
2   CS1-1     2     30000.0          NaN  None       0.0
3   CS1-2     1     10000.0          NaN  None       NaN
1   CS1-2     2     20000.0          0.0  None       0.0
5   CS1-2     3     30000.0          NaN  None       NaN
4  CS1-11     1         NaN          0.0  None       NaN
```

This is under the assumption that your ID column follows the pattern "XXX-NUMBER".

---

A fool-proof solution will involve the use of the [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io) module, which excels at fast natural sorting. With a little elbow-grease, we can argsort your data.

```
from natsort import natsorted
idx, *_ = zip(*natsorted(
    zip(df.index, df.ID, df.Time), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2])))

df.iloc[list(idx)]

       ID  Time  oneMissing  singleValue empty  oneEmpty
0   CS1-1     1     10000.0          NaN  None       0.0
2   CS1-1     2     30000.0          NaN  None       0.0
3   CS1-2     1     10000.0          NaN  None       NaN
1   CS1-2     2     20000.0          0.0  None       0.0
5   CS1-2     3     30000.0          NaN  None       NaN
4  CS1-11     1         NaN          0.0  None       NaN
```

Use PyPi to install: `pip install natsort`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what pattern the ID will have, that's up to the user to decide. What I know is that the ID's will contain letters and numbers and I need to compare numbers as a number, not the letter value.

Comment: @Mackan I've edited in a foolproof alternative using the `natsort` module that should work for any arbitrary structured column.

Comment: Thanks for the foolproof alternative!

Comment: @coldspeed "Fool-proof"... thanks for the high praise of `natsort`!

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This method assumes you wish to sort numerically by `X` for `ID`s of the form `ABC-X`.**

[`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) supports sorting by multiple series, and avoids having to add an extra series to your dataframe. This example sorts by the *suffix* of `ID` numerically and *then* by `Time`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

id_num = df['ID'].str.split('-').str[-1].astype(int)

df = df.iloc[np.lexsort((df['Time'], id_num))]

print(df)

       ID  Time  oneMissing  singleValue empty  oneEmpty
0   CS1-1     1     10000.0          NaN  None       0.0
2   CS1-1     2     30000.0          NaN  None       0.0
3   CS1-2     1     10000.0          NaN  None       NaN
1   CS1-2     2     20000.0          0.0  None       0.0
5   CS1-2     3     30000.0          NaN  None       NaN
4  CS1-11     1         NaN          0.0  None       NaN
```

Comment: This won't work for the same reason as my first option doesn't - as outlined by OP in a comment under my answer...

Comment: @coldspeed, Sure.. wasn't clear before the edit. I'll add a disclaimer on top so at least future visitors know what this method achieves.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values(['ID','Time'])
```

NB if you want `CS1-11` to come after `CS1-2` (which is not the standard string ordering) you may need to introduce a length column e.g.

```
df['len_ID'] = df['ID'].str.len()
df.sort_values(['len_ID', 'ID','Time'])
```

Comment: that wont produce the expected output as `CS1-11` will still be before `CS1-2`

Comment: Exactly, that is what I tried to start with, when I understood that I needed to sort in another way to sort numbers correctly.

Comment: Most genius way among the answers

Answer (score 1):

The desired output can be achieved using `sorted` to sort on a subset of the ID string - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728018/4028718):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    sorted(df.values, key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('-')[1])),
    columns=df.columns
)
```

N.B. here the lambda function is taking the characters after the '-' in ID, casting to a int and then sorting these. This achieves the 'natural' ordering.

```
       ID  Time  oneMissing  singleValue empty  oneEmpty
0   CS1-1     1     10000.0          NaN  None       0.0
1   CS1-1     2     30000.0          NaN  None       0.0
2   CS1-2     2     20000.0          0.0  None       0.0
3   CS1-2     1     10000.0          NaN  None       NaN
4   CS1-2     3     30000.0          NaN  None       NaN
5  CS1-11     1         NaN          0.0  None       NaN
```

Comment: Same answer as mine. And you are forgetting to take into account the `Time` column to sort.

Comment: It is very similar to yours (apologies I didn't see yours when posting). I was working on the assumption of the data already being in a dataframe rather than in a list. You're right, I missed the Time column secondary sort - nice trick with  `+ [x[1]]` in your answer