# Sorting a pandas dataframe column by length and alphanumerically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have scoured this forum, and have yet to find a solution to my problem. I am using pandas dataframes, and I need to order this column, which of type string because its alphanumeric, by two attributes, length being first, then alphanumerically. The input will be something like this:

```
input = [10, 100110, 222754430, 777000, TEST10, 800022110, 210, 1960, 30, TERM20, 22100, 22300, 487854750, TEST20, 2200010, 220, 20, 22200, 1100, 2200020]

output = [10, 20, 30, 210, 220, 1100, 1960, 22100, 22200, 22300, TERM20, TEST10, TEST20, 100110, 777000, 2200010, 2200020, 222754430, 487854750, 800022110]
```

If someone could help, that would be great! Any extra info can be provided

I tried sorting by length, which partially worked, but not entirely. I also tried sort_values, but it sorts in something like: 10, 100110, 210, 220, 777000, etc. This has been stumping me for something that feels so trivial.

Comment: That sounds like [natural string sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870683/natural-sorting-in-pandas). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can try:

```py
lst = [
    10,
    100110,
    222754430,
    777000,
    "TEST10",
    800022110,
    210,
    1960,
    30,
    "TERM20",
    22100,
    22300,
    487854750,
    "TEST20",
    2200010,
    220,
    20,
    22200,
    1100,
    2200020,
]


def key_fn(val):
    if isinstance(val, str):
        return len(val), False, val
    else:
        s = str(val)
        return len(s), True, s

output = sorted(lst, key=key_fn)
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
[
    10,
    20,
    30,
    210,
    220,
    1100,
    1960,
    22100,
    22200,
    22300,
    "TERM20",
    "TEST10",
    "TEST20",
    100110,
    777000,
    2200010,
    2200020,
    222754430,
    487854750,
    800022110,
]
```

---

EDIT: To apply it to the dataframe you can do e.g.:

```py
def key_fn(series):
    def __to_int(val):
        try:
            return int(val)
        except:
            return val

    def __inner(val):
        val = __to_int(val)

        if isinstance(val, str):
            return len(val), False, val
        else:
            s = str(val)
            return len(s), True, s

    return pd.Series([__inner(val) for val in series], index=series.index)


df = df.sort_values(by=["column1"], key=key_fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      column1
0          10
16         20
8          30
6         210
15        220
18       1100
7        1960
10      22100
17      22200
11      22300
9      TERM20
4      TEST10
13     TEST20
1      100110
3      777000
14    2200010
19    2200020
2   222754430
12  487854750
5   800022110
```

Comment: I tried to incorporate this against a dataframe I'm working with's column and cannot seem to get it working correctly. Would you be able to help?

Comment: @Trooprm32 I've updated my answer.

Comment: Amazing, this worked!! Thank you Andrej!